# example using Quartz SendMailJob

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, quartz-scheduler

I am looking for assistance using the SendMailJob class in Quartz scheduler.   I've been unable to find any useful documentation and have not been able to figure out the 'right' way to implement it for sending bulk mails on demand from a web app (such that the process isn't dependent on the servlet continuing to exist throughout the lifecycle of the email job)

Answer (score -1):

This class provides very basic options to send mails. You should better rewrite your own class that will be much more integrated with your application. The `SendMailJob` seems to be present as en example much as a production class...

Any way, if you want to use it, you must populate the following parameters in the JobData map in order to send a mail. If you need more details, take a look in the source code of this class.

```
/**
 * The host name of the smtp server. REQUIRED.
 */
public static final String PROP_SMTP_HOST = "smtp_host";

/**
 * The e-mail address to send the mail to. REQUIRED.
 */
public static final String PROP_RECIPIENT = "recipient";

/**
 * The e-mail address to cc the mail to. Optional.
 */
public static final String PROP_CC_RECIPIENT = "cc_recipient";

/**
 * The e-mail address to claim the mail is from. REQUIRED.
 */
public static final String PROP_SENDER = "sender";

/**
 * The e-mail address the message should say to reply to. Optional.
 */
public static final String PROP_REPLY_TO = "reply_to";

/**
 * The subject to place on the e-mail. REQUIRED.
 */
public static final String PROP_SUBJECT = "subject";

/**
 * The e-mail message body. REQUIRED.
 */
public static final String PROP_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * The message content type. For example, "text/html". Optional.
 */
public static final String PROP_CONTENT_TYPE = "content_type";
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't provide any guidance on how to actually use the example - it just lists out the constants.

Comment: when you schedule this job, popuplate the parameter map with the values you want to use. jobData.put("smtp_host", "mail.google.com"), jobData.put("subject", "some news!"), ... But as you can see you have a very limited parameters that must be known when you schedule the job. That's why I'll discourage you to use this class and rewrite your own dynamic SendMailJob